# Appending unique mixed string using pandas or python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, counter

I have a table or df(if pandas has a better way) with one of the columns with multiple mixed character and string, i need to count them and append a unique mixed string to it, what would be best way to do a python loop or pandas has some syntax to do it? example data

```
col0     col1 col2
ENSG0001 E001 ENSG001:E001
ENSG0001 E002 ENSG001:E002
.
.
ENSG001  E028 ENSG001:E028
ENSG002  E001 ENSG002:E001
.
ENSG002  E012 ENSG002:E012
```

Edit:
Need to count the elements in col0 and instead of a number I need E001 as the counter and concatenate col0 and col1 in col2

Comment: Can you add desired output?

Comment: This looks like just `df['col2'] = df['col0'] + ':' + df['col1']`

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to column `Series` created by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to `string` + [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html).

```
df['col3'] = df['col0'] + ':E' + 
             df.groupby('col0').cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
print (df)
       col0  col1          col2           col3
0  ENSG0001  E001  ENSG001:E001  ENSG0001:E001
1  ENSG0001  E002  ENSG001:E002  ENSG0001:E002
2   ENSG001  E028  ENSG001:E028   ENSG001:E001
3   ENSG002  E001  ENSG002:E001   ENSG002:E001
4   ENSG002  E012  ENSG002:E012   ENSG002:E002
```

Comment: Glad can help you, nice day!